# What can I do with paprika jelly?

Tags: culinary-uses, gelatin, jelly, pectin

I've made paprika jelly before (combined with raspberry flavour), and I quite like the novel flavour. It kind of reminds me of chili chocolate, but more water based - in a sorbet over ice cream kind of way. I don't think I would eat it by itself though, as it didn't feel like it could hold up on its own. My question is if anyone has any ideas for how to combine it, or use it in a dish/complete meal?

Some ideas I have are:

- An inbetween dish to clear the palate - I found that the spiciness of the paprika and the watery-ness of the jelly was good in clearing the palate of meaty tastes
- Some savoury jelly, like on the top of pate

Comment: I don't know the specific characteristics of this particular jelly, but I've had a number of hot pepper jellies that go very well on sandwiches (fried eggs, ham, etc.)  I've also seen recommendations to mix them with cream cheese as a dip or spread.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a gourmet grilled cheese sandwich! If it's very sweet, you could combine it with a more savory cheese and perhaps a fruit like fig. It reminds me of something the patron saint of grilled cheese would use on her blog: http://www.grilledcheesesocial.com/.

Answer (score 2):

This would probably be good as an ingredient in a barbecue sauce, assuming the jelly will mix into the other components.

Answer (score 1):

I should like to try that with Lamb Chops.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a good layer in a terrine or mousse to me, or you could make a cold pie and pour in the jelly as in a [British Pork Pie](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14038/why-do-they-put-the-jelly-like-substance-in-pork-pies).